# Select distinct columns from table tournament and max winner player

Tags: java, mysql, sql, group-by

I've search a bit, without an answer, I'm doing an exercise and I have 4 tables

Table "tournament as t"

| ID | NAME | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roland Garros | RG |
| 2 | Australian open | AO |
| 3 | US open | US |
| 4 | Wimbledon | WI |

...

Table "trial as e"

| ID | YEAR | GENDER_TRIAL | ID_TOURNAMENT (fk_toTournament) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | Male | 1 |
| 2 | 2010 | Female | 1 |
| 3 | 2011 | Female | 2 |
| 4 | 2011 | Male | 2 |
| 5 | 2011 | Male | 1 |

...

Table "match_tennis as mt"

| ID | ID_trial (fk_toTrial) | ID_winner (fk_toPlayer) | ID_loser (fk_toPlayer) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

...

Table "player as p"
| ID | name            | gender |
|:--:|:---------------:|:------:|
| 1  | Rafael Nadal    | Male   |
| 2  | Roger Federer   | Male   |
| 3  | Serena Williams | Female |
| 2  | Williams Venus  | Female |

...

So my tables have many records, and the expected result is

| ID (t.id) | Tournament (t.Name) | Code (t.Code) | Female Player with most wins (p.Name) | Wins (MAX(COUNT(WINNER))) | Male Player with most wins (p.Name) | Wins (MAX(COUNT(WINNER))) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roland Garros | RG | Serena Williams | 5 | Rafael Nadal | 7 |
| 2 | Australian open | AO | Venus Williams | 3 | Roger Federer | 9 |
| 3 | US open | US | Simona Halep | 7 | Novak Djokovic | 5 |
| 4 | Wimbledon | WI | Wozniacki Caroline | 3 | Andy Murray | 4 |

Something like that ... I can't change my database tables, so far I got all the tournaments with all the wins from each player

my query is like that

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.code, p.name, COUNT(*) as wins "
                + "FROM tournament t "
                + "INNER JOIN trial e ON e.id_tournament = t.id "
                + "INNER JOIN match_tennis mt ON mt.id_trial = e.id "
                + "INNER JOIN player p ON mt.id_winner = p.id "
                + "GROUP BY t.name, p.name "
                + "ORDER BY wins DESC";
```

And I have something like this as the expected output
[image: https://prnt.sc/112yvgr]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: 1. At least, the sample data `Table "match_tennis as mt"` does not match your expected result. 2. What version of your MySQL?

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow.. i mean, posting questions, its like my third... Concerning the table i could give you the queries to create and populate the database, but idk how... The expected result is and example its not related to the other tables, nor is match_tennis in fact... ill edit it to clearify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start by thinking of how to get each player/tournament combination with the number of wins.

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.code, e.gender_trial, p.name as player_name, COUNT(*) as wins
FROM tournament t INNER JOIN
     trial e
     ON e.id_tournament = t.id INNER JOIN
     match_tennis mt
     ON mt.id_trial = e.id INNER JOIN
     player p
     ON mt.id_winner = p.id
GROUP BY t.id, t.name, t.code, e.gender_trial, p.name;
```

This is very similar to your query, but the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` are consistent and it also includes the gender.

With this result you can do two things.  The first is to calculate the first per gender.  The second is to aggregate each tournament into one row.  So:

```
WITH tp as (
      SELECT t.id, t.name, t.code, e.gender_trial, p.name, COUNT(*) as wins 
      FROM tournament t INNER JOIN
           trial e
           ON e.id_tournament = t.id INNER JOIN
           match_tennis mt
           ON mt.id_trial = e.id INNER JOIN
           player p
           ON mt.id_winner = p.id
      GROUP BY t.id, t.name, t.code, e.gender_trial, p.name
     )
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.code,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND gender_trial = 'Female' THEN player_name END)) as female_first, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND gender_trial = 'Female' THEN wins END)) as female_wins,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND gender_trial = 'Male' THEN player_name END)) as male_first, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND gender_trial = 'Male' THEN wins END)) as male_wins
FROM (SELECT tp.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, gender_trial ORDER BY wins DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tp
     ) tp
GROUP BY t.id, t.name, t.code;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately its not working, I wrote exactly the same thing, it show me an error "Duplicate column name 'name'".

Comment: @TiagoVieira . . . I missed that you are using `name` twice in your query.

Comment: Im getting null on male_first and male_wins... If i'm not wrong, partition clause is dividing all the results by tournament and its gender, right? so we have like i.e. a columns will all Roland Garros and Females players, and everytime row_number gets the 1st line of that partition, it defines de max wins and the player_name, or am I wrong? I just saw an youtube video cause its all new for me... Anyway it was good for female, but male is sending null.

Comment: NVM my bad, I misspelt "Male" :D oh god sir, you are amazing, I hope I get to you level :) thank you very much, really appreciated your help.